# jQuery treeview with sortable

Tags: jquery, treeview, tree, jquery-ui-sortable

I was just wondering if anyone knows of any way to get the bassistance treeview plugin to work with jQuery UI's sortable plugin? Particularly in terms of being able to drag and drop the element from it's nested ul to the parent ul or vice versa. Two other requirements are that I have the ability to prevent dropping onto specified elements (for example: element with class="no-drop"), and the ability to reference a function after the drop event.

If there is no real feasible way of doing this with those plugins, does anyone happen to know of another plugin?

Kind Regards,
Remy

Answer (score 6):

I did have the same problem, have a look at [nested sortable](http://code.google.com/p/nestedsortables/). It probably is too late but might be helpful for others later.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/

Answer (score 1):

The [jstree](http://jstree.com) plugin has a pretty solid code base with, for example, many events to attach your own logic to.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to do this, I have got some basic sorting working by setting the handle to 'span', but I cannot seem to sort from one UL to another.

I tried using combine: 'ul' but that does not seem to work.