# JQuery Sortable tree or nested list plugin in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, nested-lists, nested-sortable

I'm looking for a plugin for Sortable nested list or tree that work correctly in IE and if it's possible in Quirks mode too....

As there are always problem with `JQuery` and `CSS` in quirks mode especially in IE,of course I may have to do some adjusting in Quirks mode but I really need this plugin to work completely in IE

And if this plugin happens to free it would be much better
I've done a lot of searching and I'm pretty stuck now...So I appreciate if someone could help me with this

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394494/jquery-treeview-with-sortable

Comment: also  http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/

Comment: thanks for answering...the first link hasn't got my answer however it does contain the second link you posted...I came across the same site this morning and the demo works perfectly even in quirks mode however when I go to the site it refers to download it, the file is kind of different and when I check it in IE, it doesn't work like it should...